# C++ Boost Serialization boost::archive_exception: Output stream error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am running the following C++ code with Boost serialization library, which first serializes the object of class Info and then retrieves it back in another object of class Info:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class Info
{
private:
  // Allow serialization to access non-public data members.
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  // Serialize the std::vector member of Info
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & filenames;
  }

  std::vector<std::string> filenames;

public:
  void AddFilename( const std::string& filename );
  void Print() const;
};

void Info::Print() const
{
  std::copy(filenames.begin(), filenames.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

void Info::AddFilename( const std::string& filename )
{
  filenames.push_back( filename );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Info info;
  info.AddFilename( "ThisFile.txt" );
  info.AddFilename( "ThatFile.txt" );
  info.AddFilename( "OtherFile.txt" );
   // Save filename data contained in Info object
  {
    // Create an output archive
    std::ofstream ofs( "store.dat" );
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
    ar & info;
  }

  // Restore from saved data and print to verify contents
  Info restored_info;
  {
    // Create and input archive
    std::ifstream ifs( "store.dat" );
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(ifs);
    // Load the data
    ar & restored_info;
  }

  restored_info.Print();

  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  output stream error
Aborted (core dumped)`

It would be really great, if someone can help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to run your code with boost 1.55 and vs 2010 and I had no error. Which boost version and which compiler are you using ?

Comment: boost 1.57 and gcc 4.8.1

Comment: Compiling and Linking command : `g++ -I /home/wamiq/Desktop/boost_build/include/ demo.cpp -L /usr/lib/ -lboost_serialization`

Comment: I just tried it quickly using babun on my windows workstation (gcc 4.9.2 and boost 1.55) and also works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe there is a mismatch between your compiler and the one used to compile boost libraries (if you didn't compiled them yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH fixes the problem
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH = path\to\boost\lib\`
`export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`